# iOS 6 4-inch device screen scale is 2.0 is that a bug, is it correct for height?

Tags: iphone, ios

Just test the property [UIScreen mainScreen].scale on iphone5 4-inch simulator, the value is 2.0 , is that a bug?

[update] Thanks Tommy, I got the wrong idea for the bound size of the iphone5, the new bound size is 320x568, so the scale is 2.0 still.

Comment: Are you expecting a different value?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that the device is iphone5 4-inch simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on a retina device, the scale will be 2.0.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that the device is iphone5 4-inch simulator, is it correct for the height?

Comment: Yes, if it's the retina simulator then it will return 2.0. I don't think there's a non-retina 4 inch simulator.

Comment: if it's 2.0, the height for iphone5 should be 480x2 not current 1136

Comment: There isn't; all 4" screens are retina and the simulator simulates only a retina screen at 4". If there's any confusion at all then presumably it's that the simulator can run at 75% or 50% scale? That's just a Mac-side effect, it has no footprint in iOS.

Comment: @VincentSong the screen bounds will be 320x568, the scale factor will be 2. The scale factor is number of pixels per point. The point size is in the bounds.

Comment: @Tommy thanks, I got it now, so the scale is always 2 but the point size is changed.